# Why MongoDB Java driver didn't recover after SemaphoresOut errors?

Tags: java, mongodb, dropwizard

At 1:00 AM our servers received a large amount of requests, this understandably lead to the follwing error :

```
com.mongodb.DBPortPool$SemaphoresOut: Concurrent requests for database connection have exceeded limit of 500
```

Then this error:

```
com.mongodb.DBPortPool$ConnectionWaitTimeOut: Connection wait timeout after 120000 ms
```

After 5 minutes CloudWatch shows that the requests went back to normal (very few requests) but the driver kept reporting the connection timeout error. After 6 hours when we noticed the error we restarted the server and everything went to normal, but kept me thinking what could be the cause of MongoDB driver stuck in a bad state and didn't recover right away when requests rate went down (fyi we use DropWizard/Jetty to handle APIs request).